# Aligning the height of views in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view which is an `HStack` of two views:
1. A simple `Text` view, which acts as sort of a label, and is always a single line
2. A custom UIKit view which is a `UITextView` with lots of custom formatting

My desire is to restrict the height of the `UITextView` to match the height of the `Text` view (single line, height dependent on system fonts, etc). I've tried many ways to go about this, but I can't seem to find something that works. `GeometryReader` seems to only pass parent attributes to child, but doesn't solve the "sibling" issue.

Any ideas or insight?

Comment: can you please paste your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible layout. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iSO 13.4

[image: demo]

Note: `.border` and `.padding` are added just for demo & better visibility. Important places are marked in comment. `MultilineTextView` is a simple representable of `UITextView`

```
struct DemoFixedToLabel: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Some Text").font(Font.system(.title))
                .padding()
                .border(Color.blue)
                .fixedSize()             // << here !!
            MultilineTextView(text: .constant("My desire is to restrict the height of the UITextView to match the height of the Text"))
                .border(Color.green)
        }
        .padding()
        .border(Color.red)
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)    // << here !!
    }
}
```